# Is there a module for google maps in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities, google-maps

On a site that I am building (using drupal 7), there is a feature that I need to include that I can't seem to find; Google maps. I am looking for two things;

1: something that will allow you to put in your home address, and it will give you directions to a preset location

2: something that will allow you to imbed a map of the surrounding area of a preset destination by stating the location in a CCK

do either of these exist? if so, where can I find them?

I need it to look like this:
where instead of an image, the map is actually an embedded google map.
[image]

Comment: Why not embed a screenshot into the page?

Answer (score 5):

There is the [GMap Module](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) module, but there is just a development snapshot, for Drupal 7.

Comment: the only thing that gave me was a link to google maps, I need an embedded google map displaying.

Comment: To show a map go to manage display (of the content type), then set the location field (the field for the map) to be shown as a map

Comment: @Ephraim you can display map instead of link to map. Please dig in to settings.

Answer (score -1):

There is the [Simple Google Maps](https://drupal.org/project/simple_gmap) module.

> This module is about the simplest way to get a Google Map, and/or a link to a Google Map, displayed with your content. It provides a field formatter for Drupal 7 text fields. With this formatter, you can enter a single-line address that Google Maps would recognize into a plain text field, such as: 100 Madison Ave, New York, NY.
>   And then on your Manage Display screen (or in Views field setup), you can choose to display the field with an embedded iframe Google Map, a link to a Google Maps map, or both; with or without the original address text.